# What's the difference between "life" and "non-life"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-biology

How is "life" objectively defined?

Comment: 'Objective' is a hollow, meaningless addition in the question. Yes, there are philosophies with a clear-cut difference. Most of them come with some phenomenological difference like specialised parts working in unison to sustain and expand the processes within a certain gestalt and the gestalt itself. Others are [different](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37364/is-there-a-philosophical-conception-of-not-necessarily-biological-life/37398#37398). But the whole "prove" and "objective" part does nothing but obscure the question and makes it more about opinion and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scientific border between life and non-life as you say. From a historical point of view we first separated things to organics and non-organics up until 1828 that a scientist, Wohler, made an organic compound called urea from some inorganic compounds. And today we know that all organic compounds are made up of inorganic ones. But your question is a bit harder to answer because the definition of life is not that obvious. If life means living organic things then there is still a way to separate a live organic stuff from a dead one by their physical/thermodynamical state.

From the simplest organic compound, urea, to the most sophisticated organ on the planet earth, human brain, there are different borders that can also be considered as the border between life and non-life, for example some biologists believe that viruses are the smallest living things because they can reproduce and conserve their RNA, most others believe that biological cells like bacteria are the first living things due to the reproduction of the whole cell using their DNA. There are also other borders, for example living things are energy/mass consuming they must be constantly fed. What ever you chose to be the border you'll find out that it's not something special and you could have chosen another border. It's not an objective border, it's just a  definitive border.

Comment: Precisely, there's no boundary, otherwise, the answer would be simple. Another opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of potential criteria which have been suggested and the potential exceptions to each putative criteria make this a somewhat difficult question to answer unambiguously. Nevertheless the most plausible candidates are

1. Living things *do* or have the *potential* to undergo the process of
   darwinian evolution
2. Living Things are information processing 'machines' (if you will)
   whose causal capacities and downstream behavior are dependent both
   on stored prior information (DNA) and to the experiences manifest in
   their respective lives
3. Living things are uniquely *intentional* homogeneous forms of matter
   which have the capacity for (some form of) representation, by which   novel causal (possibilities) are made actual.

Though there are many others, the most plausible involve information retaining and modifying capacity, which imply the possibility of alternative histories depending on the set of actualities which occur. These are dependent on the information processing mechanisms made possible by the existence and function of DNA and correlated gene expression, which are causally necessitated by the organism being involved in evolutionary processes.

Comment: I like "life is what evolves" as a strong mapping to the common language intent - although I'd suggest "life is a *material* process that evolves", to exclude e.g. codes of laws, chess-learning computer programs.

Answer (score 0):

When I was at school, which was a long time ago and so things may have changed somewhat, we were taught that living organisms exhibit a number of properties:

- they move
- they reproduce
- They make new cytoplasm
- They respire
- They respond to stimuli
  And probably one or two others.  This still more or less holds up since self-replicating machines are still rather limited.  However, this definition tells us how to identify a living organism rather than telling us what life *is*.  It would be fair to say that life is a property of living organisms rather than a thing in itself and so you could argue that it doesn’t exist depending on your definition of ‘exist’.  By such a definition you would probably also say that other properties such as size, weight and time don’t exist, which seems counterintuitive to me but of course a word can mean anything that we agree it means.

Comment: I think this depends on one's view of whether there are [natural kinds](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-kind/), and if so whether "life" is one--if something is a natural kind, we may say that a definition that picks out all members of that kind and nothing else is more "natural" than other definitions that don't correspond to natural kinds. I think few modern scientists would consider "life" to be a natural kind in the metaphysical sense of a category with 100% objective boundaries, though--that's what I interpret the point of the Scientific American article to be.

Comment: All such features can be observed in a rock: it moves and changes shape very slowly, can break in two, and the parts grow due to accumulation of minerals -reproduction-, can produce equivalents to cytoplasm very slowly (cytoplasm already implies life, which is a fallacy: citoplasm defines life and not the opposite), can "respire" producing chemical reactions in the air, very slowly, and oppose an action with a reaction, or producing chemicals if subject to pressure, both of which are answers to stimuli. That view of life is very old.

Comment: @RodolfoAP I’m inclined to agree on the whole.  I disagree though with your assertion that cytoplasm defines life.  If you would like to our forward a different definition of life then I’d be interested to hear it.

Answer (score -3):

Life *tries.*

Nonliving chemical processes don't *try* anything. When they run out of resources, they simply stop.

Living beings *try* to keep on living. They do whatever they can to keep on going:

- They *try* actions to collect more resources (energy and building blocks)
- They *try* to use the resources to maintain and improve their own ability to collect and use resources
- They *try* to multiply to keep the species alive despite the eventual death of the individual.

Here is Dr Jeremy Sherman describing the difference between living and dead:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDBC4k0vjEg

Comment: I can say that a teddy bear _tries_ to keep its integrity (proved that it does not break easily), so, according to this definition, the teddy bear is alive. Evidently, "life tries" is not measurable, not formal, not science from any perspective, and it is mostly a subjective interpretation. Teddy bears are alive because they try, for a huge number of people (kids), so, they must be alive...?

Comment: A protozoon does not *try* anything either. It just *does*. The very notion of *trying* implies the representation of a state different from what is. This, in turn, certainly is not the case for anything that does not have a brain, even according to the more liberal philosophies when it comes to consciousness in animals. Prime example of anthropomorphic fallacy imho.

Comment: Trying does not require a brain. In the simplest of life forms trying is just a causal reaction   that improves the odds of survival.

Comment: As stated, this is an illegitimate projection of *our* notion of how things can/should be onto something that does not exist in these categories. The pragmatic context of *trying* vs. *doing*, as a notion and symbolic representation of a state, is exactly that trying describes the conscious effort to achieve a certain state. Plants do not literally *try* to grow towards the light, the chemical reactions in their structures are so that if sunlight hits one side of the stem more than the other, the growth there is locally inhibited more and thus there is an automatic alignment towards the light.

Comment: Automatic reactions do not ensure survival, but they do serve the purpose of trying to keep the individual being alive. If you are unwilling to call an attempt to improve odds of survival *trying*, then what is the word you would rather use?

Comment: They just do follow their genetic programming in interaction with their environment. All the time. The first level of life where you can question that is where there is a complete, central neuronal representation of the body in its environment. Philosophy is sceptical of uncritically applying the notion of *purpose* on nature since at least Kant, since it implies someone who conceived and installed things according to purpose, ie. implies agency of or behind nature itself. While there are fringe positions holding that, this is certainly screaming for citations and justifications.

Comment: Genetic programming, yes. That genetic programming does things that improve the odds of survival, serve that purpose. Nature as a whole does not serve any purpose, naturally. A purpose is a future state of affairs that an *individual being* attempts to achieve.

Comment: A protozoon "tries" to stay alive by being pushed away by the current to where there is more food just as much as a cloud "tries" to stay big by being pushed by the wind over the sea. Also, "attempt" to do something requires some way of representation, of imagining the goal of what is being attempted. So by your own definition "trying" requires a brain. Unicellulars can't figure the possible future state of things and therefore can't "attempt" anything.

Comment: I find your petty bickering about my choice of words quite irrelevant as you have offered me no other word to describe the phenomenon that makes the difference between alive and dead. I suppose you both agree on the *idea*, am I right?

Comment: No, I do not agree that the difference between alive and dead is a strive for an improvement of the odds of survival. That is evidently false for even higher individual life forms, and it is circular since only what is alive can survive. And it has nothing to do with the functions and inner states of life itself. This whole teleological thinking is bound to **our** mode of living, which is obviously quite different from the life of plants and protozoon. I linked one philosophical suggestion in a link in a comment to the question.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Do you seriously disagree with the notion that living things try to keep on living, while dead matter does not try to do anything? How can you disagree with such an obvious observed and verified difference in behaviour?

Comment: Counter question: How does "living things survive (live) and dead things don't" tell us anything about how to differentiate the two? It is completely circular, a tautology. A protozoon and a stone both behave to their environment according to their inner laws, following perfectly determinable causal laws. There is no verifiable or phenomenologically significant difference to be made in what you suggest there. So at the moment where you say 'look, the protozoon tries to survive' you can do so only according to other criteria or you presupposed what is to be determined, ie. that it is life.